# Video getting ahead of audio during recording HLS

Tags: objective-c, audio, video, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I have a problem where I'm using the Kickflip.io (see code base which is in github) base and building off of it, but after about 10+ seconds the video is getting ahead of the audio.  I was able to verify that the audio is playing at the correct rate, so its definitely the video.

I've tried adjusting the sample frame rate for the video down to 10 fps, and this does nothing.  Based on all the other audio out of sync with video which is out there for FFMpeg, I'm starting to wonder if there's something in the FFMpeg cocoa pod.

My guess is that the issue is in:
https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-ios-sdk/blob/master/Kickflip/Outputs/Muxers/HLS/KFHLSWriter.m

Comment: Consider posting some code.

Comment: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg

Comment: also https://github.com/Kickflip

Comment: I think it's easier for us as people who can potentially answer your question to know the particular file or place in a file we are trying to improve.

Comment: The problem I'm running into is that I'm not exactly sure where the problem is.  I'm guessing that there's an issue somewhere in FFMpeg, but only because all of the knowledge base articles around video audio sync issues.  The Kickflip.io is a working source, which can be compiled and repro the issue I'm running into, so I thought it would be better as you'd have everything.  Otherwise I'd have around 10,000+ lines of source I'd have to put here

Comment: Here's my best guess as to where the issue lies. https://github.com/Kickflip/kickflip-ios-sdk/blob/master/Kickflip/Outputs/Muxers/HLS/KFHLSWriter.m

Comment: Now put that file as code into your question. Mention that that is where you _think_ the error is.

Comment: Alright, so I also think I've gotten further on the issue.  It looks like FFOutputFile is not thread safe, and increments its current frame after writing to the file, and on line 113, its being sent data trough a dispatch.  My theory is that this can cause a race condition where two writes can occur for the same frame count, then increment the codec twice.  Not exactly sure if this could cause the exact issue, but given the way its being accessed there might be something there

Comment: Alright, so we've ruled out the FFOutputFile not being thread safe.  We've also verified that the video before being adjusted by FFMpeg appears to be correct, and only after the conversion to HLS does the file become problematic